# jQuery animate position not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just playing with `animate` of jQuery and not getting the position of a list element to animate.
I've set the list position to be `relative` of an `absolute` unordered list but still not seeing this happening.

Here is the snippet and demo is here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/wzmh63xb/1/)

HTML

```
<button>click</button>
<ul class="nav">
    <li>Look</li>
    <li>Play</li>
    <li>Eat</li>
    <li>See</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
var menu = $('.nav').children('li');

  $('button').on('click', function () {
      menu[0].animate({
          'top': '+=50'
      }, 200);
  });
```

Comment: Try `menu.first().animate`. `menu` is a jQuery object so you want to reference it properly.

Comment: Thanks. I tried different naming to avoid any keyword but it will seem to want to be wrapped in $(). I've come across tutorials that didn't conform to that rule but seemed to work. Strange.

Comment: What you saw in the tutorial is probably without selecting the actual element via `[0]` or something similar. Using the `$()` selector returns an object that has the jQuery functions defined while adding `[0]` would return an element which don't have those functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$(menu[0])` instead.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Can you please add why I can't just use this variable without wrapping as jQuery object?

Comment: You need to wrap it because `.animate()` isn't a function of an element, it's a function of jQuery. So if you try to run `.animate()` on an element, it's not defined and therefore doesn't work. If you open the developer console via F12, you'll see that it tells you that `menu[0].animate is not defined` every time you hit the button.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now, will accept your answer when I can.